# NDVI calculation of Color-Infrared Image in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, ndvi

I have a color infrared image of an agricultural field. The color infrared image contains 3 different bands; NIR, Red, and Green (order maintained here).
To calculate the NDVI, I am currently using the "Image Analysis" tool of ArcMap (shown below). [image]

However, I am writing a larger python script where calculating the NDVI from the color infrared image is a part. If I had two different single band rasters, I could have used the raster calculator. But, in this case, I only got one Color Infrared raster which contains 3 different bands. Is there any way to calculate the NDVI using the Color Infrared raster with ArcPy?

Comment: You could try to use the [Make Raster Layer tool](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013385) to split the appropriate bands in your CIR raster. Then you can use raster calculator in your script to produce the NDVI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [arcpy.Raster() objects](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm), which let you specify the band by appending it to the path:

```
>>> out_raster = arcpy.Raster(r"C:\Temp\test.tif\Band_1") + arcpy.Raster(r"C:\Temp\test.tif\Band_2")
>>> out_raster.save(r"C:\Temp\test_sum.tif")
```